# Firefox extension: how to get a script to run from a load overlay

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have got the extension to load and have been able to make a status appear at the bottom.  I have tried to add the following code to the chrome.manifest file:

```
chrome.manifest:

content     sample    chrome/content/
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://sample/content/sample.xul
```

Then in sample.xul, I have the following:

```
sample.xul:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay id="sample" 
         xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
 <statusbar id="status-bar" hidden="false">
  <statusbarpanel id="my-panel" label="Hello, World v2"  />
 </statusbar>

<menubar id="main-menubar">
  <menu label="Jeff" insertbefore="tools-menu">
    <menupopup>
      <menuitem label="About"/>
    </menupopup>
  </menu>
</menubar>


<script src="onloadoverlay.js"/> 

</overlay>
```

I added the menubar and statusbar to make sure that the overlay was working which it is (so far).  So in theory, the following code should be loaded from "onloadoverlay.js" when the browser starts and thus should continue to load when pages load:

```
onloadoverlay.js:

var myExtension = {
    init: function() {
        // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or unload.
        if(gBrowser) gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
    },
    onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
        var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event
        var win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc
        // test desired conditions and do something
        // if (doc.nodeName != "#document") return; // only documents
        // if (win != win.top) return; //only top window.
        // if (win.frameElement) return; // skip iframes/frames
        alert("page is loaded \n" +doc.location.href);
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
    myExtension.init();  
},false);
```

Please let me know if I am going about this completely wrong or if I am missing something simple.  I have gotten to this point with google and several extension creation walkthrough's and other information.  I would expect by the code so far that it would make a popup on page loads.

help is much appreciated,

-Jeff

Comment: hopefully someone with overlay experience can help us out. but for beginners why not start off with bootstrap addon? that doesnt need overlays or chrome.manifest, just a bootstrap.js and install.rdf, all elements though you have to createElementNS (so dynamically create and insert) or you can load a xul file using loadOverlay

Comment: @Noitidart I saw that in the walkthrough and kinda overlooked it b/c none of them shows how each file should be formed.  This is working and im pretty happy about it tho, Ive basically got the working skeleton to a extension now and im free to add whatever to it on the fly.  Every file I put in my initial post is the entire file.  File structure is as follows:

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\Profile.dev\extensions\onloadext@jeff

my_extension/chrome.manifest
my_extension/install.rdf
my_extension/chrome/content/onloadoverlay.js
my_extension/chrome/content/sample.xul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `src` attribute of the script tag to `chrome://sample/content/onloadoverlay.js`

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.  Now time to get it to only popup for the main screen and not iframes.  Much appreciated

Comment: For only main document do a test `if (window.frameElement) {` then its a frame